# How to cancel sortUsingComparator

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

When the array is sorting, [arr sortUsingComparator:sortByTime]
and then I wanna cancel the operation. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is easily possible. Presumably you are working in a concurrent environment. Then something like this should cause the sort to exit quickly. You need to sync access to the `sortCancel` BOOL when you set it as well, just as when you get it as below.

```
__block BOOL sortCancel = NO;
NSObject * lock = NSObject.new;    // Sync access to sortCancel

NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
 
    @synchronized ( lock ) {
       // Check for cancel
       if ( sortCancel ) {
         // Sort has been cancelled
         return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
       }
    }

    // 'Normal' compare, e.g.
    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
 
    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

I did not test this, but this should either break the sort or cause it to complete quickly.

I wonder why you want to abort the sorting?

Comment: My array may be changed on other threads so sorting result is inaccuracy. And if there is too much data more than 10000 or comparison conditions is complex, I think that sorting wastes CPU performance.

Comment: Thank you very much.The solution just does make the sorting faster, but it is a greet way.

Comment: Thanks - the way you describe it is what I assumed to be the case and one of the few times this would make sense. Although this is not the question you must think carefully about when you set the cancel, e.g. before those changes you mention happen. You may need to wait for the sorting to exit before you change the array. If the comparing is expensive this will help a lot, but for most control you may need to write your own sorting algo so that you can exit better than this when you need to cancel the sort.

Comment: @WalkerQiu if its about CPU you could think about caching some of the sorting if that is convenient, so repeated sorting does not have to start from scratch again. And there is `NSOrderedSet` as "datatype" if that info is of any value for ya.

Comment: Yes I fully agree with this comment. Maybe you need to sort the array fully once and thereafter when you change it do it in such a way that it remains sorted.